# Overwriting rc-calendar colors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, calendar

How can you overwrite the background colors for specific dates?
I am using this dateRender function right now:

```
dateRender = (current) => {
for(let i = 0; i < this.eventDates.length; i++) {
  if(this.eventDates[i][0] === current.year() &&
    this.eventDates[i][1] === current.month() + 1 &&
    this.eventDates[i][2] === current.date()) {
    return this.renderEventDate(current);
  }
}
return (
  <div className="rc-calendar-date">
    {current.date()}
  </div>);
```

}

How can i overwrite "rc-calendar-date" for example? I found out you can edit index.css in the module folder but thats not good to work with. Any idea how i can tell rc-calendar that i want to use a different css file?

Comment: You mean you want `<div className="rc-calendar-date">` to have different `backgroundColor`?

Comment: Exactly, i just tried changing assets/index.css which comes in the package but this didn't change the color either. To be more specific - when i click on a date, its background changes to blue. I want it to change to yellow, though